# Can we disable pipelining in ansible-playbook but have it in ansible.cfg?

Tags: ansible

I want to keep pipelining in /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg but disable it for one playbook which removes 'requiretty' in /etc/sudoers file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that this kind of option that configure connection behaviour is set for the whole ansible run.

So if you want to disable it for a single playbook (i.e. an `ansible-playbook` run), you can override `pipelining` using environment variables :

```
ANSIBLE_SSH_PIPELINING=0 ansible-playbook ...
```

This should work.

Good luck !

Answer (score 6):

With Ansible 2.0+ it is possible to handle this elegantly by overriding the setting for specific tasks:

```
- name: "task name"
  task_module:
    task_parameters: 42
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_pipelining: no
```

Answer (score 4):

You can force Ansible to connect using Paramiko instead of OpenSSH. Paramiko doesn't use pipelining:

```
- hosts: my_servers
  remote_user: centos
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  gather_facts: false
  connection: paramiko
  tasks:
    - name: disable requiretty in /etc/sudoers
      replace: regexp="^Defaults\s+requiretty$" replace="# Defaults    requiretty" dest="/etc/sudoers"
```